# How solve "sudo: must be setuid root" on Joyent server

Tags: 12.04, permissions, sudo

I have a server Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on joyent . Mistakenly I have changed the /user/* folders permission to 775. After this I cannot able to run any sudo command. Rebooting the system in recovery mode will solve the issue. But I dont know to how achive this using remote session command line.

Is there any solution, to fix this issue remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `sudo` - just log in as root with `su`, and then you should be able the change the permissions back. This should also work remotely.

There is manual page on `chmod` [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) - it has a rather useful table to work out what you need to run with `chmod`:

[image: chmod tabke]